# как вставить переменные в запрос

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, redbeanphp

пример запроса

```
$posts = R::findAll('posts', "ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 0,10");
```

Вместо 0 и 10 надо вставлять переменные. Делаю так

```
$posts = R::findAll('posts', "ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT $start,$end");
```

выводит ошибку

```
Fatal error: Uncaught [42000] - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-2 -- keep-cache' at line 1 trace: #0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
$posts = R::findAll('posts', "ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$end}");
```

или

```
$condition = "ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT {$start}, {$end}";
$posts = R::findAll('posts', $condition);
```